# После удаления какой либо записи в базе данных все остальные записи не меняют свой rowid в sqlite3

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

У меня в базе данных есть много записей, порой я удаляю какую-нибудь из них и все остальные записи не меняют свой rowid. Я использую язык программирования Python последней версии, и базу данных SQlite3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35876869/7485582 Может, вам указать тип первичного ключа `INT`, а не `INTEGER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rowid самостоятельно никогда не меняется

Comment: А как его тогда поменять?

Comment: Зачем Вам его менять?

Comment: Потому-что у меня выбывает ошибку когда я вывожу то что я вытащил из базы данных по rowid